# PHP validating query string if statement

Tags: php, validation, if-statement, query-string

This seems like it should be easy but I can't for the life of me get this to work, I'm checking a variable in a query string, if it returns a Yes it redirects to a new page. If it returns a no I want it to display an error message above the form.

My issue is with displaying the error message, it redirects when var=Yes but when it gives me var=no I can't get it to display the error message. If I replace $errormsg with header(..); it works so I know it's not my if statement.

```
if (isset($_GET['var'])) {
            $var = $_GET['var'];
            $errormsg = '';
            if ($var == 'Yes') {
                header( 'Location: http://www.google.com' ); exit;
            }
            else if ($var == 'no') {
                $errormsg = 'This is an error message.';
            }

        };
```

And this is the error message above the form:

```
<div class="errormsg"><?php echo $errormsg; ?></div>
```

My PHP ability is limited and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Silly question... but should it be "No" with a capital like the "Yes"?

Comment: I wish it was that simple, but it's actually &var=no. This is coming from a seperate service.

Comment: To little information on how this is being put together, if a redirect works in the `else if ($var == 'no') {` part, then probably `$errormsg` is not in the same scope or its being overwritten somewhere with an empty value ..

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the $var is not returning what you are expecting (possibly a "No" instead of a "no" as mjayt suggested in the comments.

First step would be to debug, and determine what $var is actually returning. Try simple print statements and go from there.

Comment: The thing is, when I place "header( 'Location: http://www.google.com' ); exit;" in the $var == 'no' statement it redirects me. So I must be doing something wrong with $errormsg.

Answer (score 0):

Try to echo $errormsg directly under the if block without any HTML. See if your text is returned.

Think you might remove that semi colon from that last curly brace also

Comment: That didn't do it, but this is on a WordPress site and I moved the PHP out of the header and onto the page template and it did work...for some reason when I was first testing I couldn't get the redirection to work unless it was in the header. Now it seems to be, thanks for everyone's help, I appreciate it, but I seem to have solved it.